# MySQL Workbench - displaying error messages

Tags: mysql-workbench

How can I make MySQL Workbench display error messages?

When I commit a syntax mistake,  MySQL Workbench shows a red cross in the line, but I don't get any further information on the error. How can I change it? I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0 and Ubuntu 22.04.

An interface of my installation of MySQL Workbench looks as below (mistakes are **intentional**):
[image: screen]

Comment: you would copy the underlined command and search it in a search machine, find a SO thread that handles it and follow the solution for this

Comment: Mistakes in commands are intentional to show the point.

Comment: when you run https://www.google.de/search?q=mysql+CREATE+DATABASE then you find why your command is faulty

Comment: Please read with understanding. know my command are faulty.  I made mistakes on purpose.

Comment: yes, but if you run the command you get a 1064 in Workbench and you get the notice to read the manual, more you will not get